# Convert .txt to .csv with AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a Lambda function which is triggered whenever a .txt file is dropped in the bucket 'testinput' (a private bucket), convert it from a .txt file (with a pipe delimiter) to a .csv file, and then put that converted file into the bucket 'testoutput' (a private bucket).

I created a Lambda function using the code below and set up the S3 trigger. I followed the steps in this [blog](https://medium.com/@melissa_89553/how-to-import-python-packages-in-aws-lambda-pandas-scipy-numpy-bb2c98c974e9) so that I could import Pandas. However, when I drop a file 'pipedelimitedtest' into 'testinput', nothing happened.

This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the code I am using for converting the .txt file to a .csv file.

If someone could provide insight into what specifically is wrong with my code, or if there is a simpler way to address this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE: I changed the script based on the helpful feedback from Marcin and added a pandas layer to the function. However, when I test the function, I am now getting the error: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'.

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='lambdatestinput985', Key='Pipedelimitedtest.txt')
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))

    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv (csv_buffer)
    
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_resource.Object(Bucket, 'df.csv').put(Body = csv_buffer.getvalue())

    return {
           'statusCode': 200,
           'body': json.dumps('Hello from S3 events Lambda!')
       }
```

Comment: The pandas package is not part of Python. In the same way as it wasn't available on your laptop until you installed it (`pip install pandas`), it's not available to your Lambda function either. But ... you probably shouldn't be using pandas in a latency-sensitive environment such as Lambda anyway. It's huge and overkill. Use the standard Python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid lambda function. You require a [lambda handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) which is an entry point to your function.

Also you need to bundle `pandas` in your lambda deployment package or use [pandas layer](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-add-python-pandas-layer-to-aws-lambda-bab5ea7ced4f) to provide pandas library to your function.

Comment: Correct answer. Additionally, I'd rather drop `pandas` all together. Reading and writing CSV is easily done with the Python standard library. Wasted effort to put Pandas into a Lambda (Layer) etc.